# How to display login form anywhere, when user isn't logged in, without redirecting?

Tags: php, functions, login

I'm currently using [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/), and I'm building a membership website where nothing is accessible to anyone, unless they're logged in.

When a user, who isn't logged in, enters anywhere on the site, they should be prompted with the *Theme My Login* login form, which essentially is designed as an individual page.

How do I get rid of the URL extension (www.example.com/login), which is where the user normally would be redirected to, and simply just showing the page template no matter where the user enters the website (e.g. */about*, */contact*, etc.), when he/she isn't logged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how theme my login works. You can do it manually by checking if an user is logged in or not:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    //user is logged in, put your regular codes
} else {
    //user isn't logged in, create a login template and call from here
    get_template_part ( 'content', 'login' ); //create your login form at content-login.php file
    //or you can use the wp built in function to load the default form
    wp_login_form();
}
```